# How to trigger Organization Scan from Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to trigger an Org Scan from a Jenkinsfile?
We are using Jenkins 2.25 with a GitHub Branch Source Plugin

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445854/how-to-set-scan-organization-triggers-via-jenkins-script-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the organisation folder job (which then scans for repos/branches) using the `build` step just like any other job. I implemented this for a multibranch job, but I assume it works the same for organisation folder jobs.

One thing to note is that currently (or at least 3 months ago when I implemented this), you can't wait for this job to be finished. If the remainder of your pipeline requires this, you need to work around a little bit. The usecase I have is that we push a new branch and then want to build that branch, so we trigger a scan, wait for the branch (=job) to appear and then finally trigger it.

```java
// Helper functions to trigger branch indexing for a certain multibranch project.
// The permissions that this needs are pretty evil.. but there's currently no other choice
//
// Required permissions:
// - method jenkins.model.Jenkins getItemByFullName java.lang.String
// - staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance
//
// See:
// https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/3ff14391fe27c8ee9ccea9ba1977131fe3b26dbe/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStepExecution.java#L66
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579229/triggering-branch-indexing-on-multibranch-pipelines-jenkins-git
void scanMultiBranchAndWaitForJob(String multibranchProject, String branch) {
    String job = "${multibranchProject}/${branch}"
    // the `build` step does not support waiting for branch indexing (ComputedFolder job type),
    // so we need some black magic to poll and wait until the expected job appears
    build job: multibranchProject, wait: false
    echo "Waiting for job '${job}' to appear..."
    // the branch could be disabled, if it had existed before and got deleted. Probably this never occurs
    // with real release branches, but might more likely occur when you touch this very file.
    while (Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job) == null || Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job).isDisabled()) {
        sleep 3
    }
}
```

and this is how it can be used:

```java
    stage('Build Artifacts') {
        steps {
            // trigger branch indexing for "PRODUCT-build" job
            echo 'Running branch indexing'
            scanMultiBranchAndWaitForJob(buildProject, releaseBranchName(version))

            // trigger "PRODUCT-build/release-1.2.0" job using the build step (wait until it finishes successfully)
            echo "Triggering build for branch '${releaseBranchName(version)}'"
            script {
                // we accept UNSTABLE builds
                buildResult = build job: "../${buildProject}/${releaseBranchName(version)}", propagate: false
                if (!buildResult.result in ['SUCCESS', 'UNSTABLE']) {
                    error "Build failed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps. If you provide more detail, answers could be a bit better tailored to you use case.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying too to force a branch I created programmatically to "appear" in Jenkins.

This can be done manually by using the mentioned "Scan" button inside the path your branch belong, but, how to it programmatically?

Using [pipeline build step plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step/) you can do:

```
build wait: false, job: {{ path where my branch is supposed to appear}} //Equivalent to clicking on "Scan" button
sleep 10 //Wait till above action is completed
build job: {{ my job full path }} //Build the job of the branch created programmatically
```

for example in my case it was:

```
build wait: false, job:"myProject/myRepo"
sleep 30
build job: "myProject/myRepo/branchCreatedProgrammatically"
```

NB: The `wait: false` parameter when doing `build` on the path is required as you cannot wait for non job items.